# Why are there ETH addresses in bitcoin wallet.dat?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, ethereum, block-hash

So I have a lot of addresses or pkscript listed in my wallet.dat files that begin with 0014....all...numbers.

There is bitcoin address on the same line starting with a 3.

When I strip the 0014 and search the blockchain, they all bring up an ETH address with 0 ETH.

Who can explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ethereum addresses are the trailing 20 bytes of keccak256(public_key). In other words, ethereum addresses are any collection of 20 bytes.

`0014{20 byte payload}` in Bitcoin is the redeem script for a p2sh-p2wpkh address. If you strip the 0014, you're left with 20 bytes. Due to the size of the ethereum address space, the vast majority of 20 byte combinations will lead to unused addresses.