# Synchronize CEX.IO wallet address

Tags: transactions

I am expecting to receive funds into my CEX.IO BTC and Ethereum wallet addresses. The sender is asking me to synchronize the wallet address I want to send the funds to. I have requested CEX.IO support to sync the wallet. No answer so far. Is there any technical procedure I can run or execute to sync the CEX.IO wallets. Any directos on this topic would be appreciate it!. Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean with "synchronize the wallet address"? Do you think that an address can be valid for Bitcoin and Ethereum at the same time?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/93433/5406

Comment: There should be separate addresses, one for BTC and another for Ethereum. I have a guy that has a spyware system asking me to pay $300 to sync my CEX.IO, BTC, and Ethereum wallets to complete the procedure of fund transfers from the spyware system. These funds we're considered lost and this guy got a spyware system to recover the funds.

Comment: It sounds like someone is trying to scam you out of $300.

Comment: That's correct. I already pay $100 to recover the funds. Now, I want to recover the lost funds by myself. Another guy scammed me as well two years ago asking upfront payments to withdraw the invested funds. That's why I will give it a try by myself. First step. Get the private key of the trust wallet watch address where the funds are. Next, code the software and bypass the wallet. Then complete the withdrawal process. Any ideas or directions on what tools should I use?